# React Note App with context and reducer

Tags: performance, beginner, react.js, jsx

In my React learning journey, I wanted to create a Note app following the SOLID principles and use as many hooks as possible to grasp things in React. If you can review my code and improve it, it would help me a lot.

***App***

```
//App.jsx
import { useEffect, useState, useReducer } from "react";
import {
  initialNotes,
  notesReducer,
  NotesContext,
  NotesDispatchContext,
} from "./components/notesContext";
import CreateNote from "./components/CreateNote";
import SearchBar from "./sections/SearchBar";
import Header from "./sections/Header";
import FilteredNotes from "./components/FilteredNotes";
export default function App() {
  //Handles notes reducer, query state for search bar, theme state for theme change and displays the components.//

  //----------------------------------------------------------------//
  /* States & Reducers */
  const [notes, dispatch] = useReducer(notesReducer, initialNotes);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(() => {
    const initialTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    return initialTheme ? initialTheme : "light";
  });
  //----------------------------------------------------------------//

  //----------------------------------------------------------------//
  /* Local Storage */
  useEffect(() => {
    getNotesFromLocalStorage();
  }, [notes]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getThemeFromLocalStorage();
  }, [theme]);

  function getNotesFromLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes));
  }
  function getThemeFromLocalStorage() {
    const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    if (savedTheme) {
      setTheme(savedTheme);
    }
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------//

  //----------------------------------------------------------------//
  /* Event Handlers */
  function toggleDarkMode() {
    setTheme((prevTheme) => {
      const newTheme = prevTheme === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
      localStorage.setItem("theme", newTheme);
      return newTheme;
    });
  }

  function updateSearchBar(e) {
    setQuery(e.target.value);
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------//
  return (
    <div
      className={`${theme === "dark" ? "dark bg-dark" : "bg-light"} font-dancing-script `}
    >
      <main className="max-container min-h-screen p-4 text-text-light dark:text-text-dark">
        <section className="flex w-full items-center justify-between py-2">
          <Header toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode} />
        </section>
        <section>
          <SearchBar query={query} onChange={updateSearchBar} />
        </section>
        <section className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-2 py-4 max-sm:grid-cols-1 ">
          <NotesDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
            <NotesContext.Provider value={notes}>
              <FilteredNotes query={query} />
            </NotesContext.Provider>
            <CreateNote />
          </NotesDispatchContext.Provider>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

***Create Note***

```
//CreateNote.jsx
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { NotesDispatchContext } from "./notesContext";

export default function CreateNote() {
  // This component handles the creation of notes.//

  //----------------------------------------------------------------//
  const [noteValue, setNoteValue] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useContext(NotesDispatchContext);

  //----------------------------------------------------------------//
  let currentDate = new Date();
  let fullDate =
    currentDate.getUTCDate() +
    "/" +
    currentDate.getUTCMonth() +
    1 +
    "/" +
    currentDate.getUTCFullYear();

  //----------------------------------------------------------------//
  function updateNote(e) {
    setNoteValue(e.target.value);
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------//
  return (
    <div className="flex h-48 flex-col justify-between gap-2 rounded-xl bg-edit-note-light p-4 shadow-xl dark:bg-edit-note-dark">
      <textarea
        aria-label="your note text"
        placeholder="Type to add a note..."
        onChange={updateNote}
        value={noteValue}
        maxLength={200}
        className="h-full min-h-6 resize-none bg-transparent text-lg italic placeholder:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none "
      ></textarea>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between h-16">
        <p>{200 - noteValue.length} remaining </p>
        <button
          aria-label="create-note-button"
          className="rounded-xl bg-note-light px-6 py-1 dark:bg-button-dark h-full"
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch({
              type: "create_note",
              text: noteValue,
              date: fullDate,
            });
            setNoteValue("");
          }}
        >
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

***Current Note***

```
//CurrentNote.jsx
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { PiTrashDuotone, PiX } from "react-icons/pi";
import { NotesDispatchContext } from "./notesContext";

export default function CurrentNote(props) {
  // This component handles the display of the current note. //

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------//
  const dispatch = useContext(NotesDispatchContext);
  const [noteValue, setNoteValue] = useState(props.text ? props.text : "");
  const [noteState, setNoteState] = useState("saved");

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------//
  function setNote(e) {
    setNoteValue(e.target.value);
  }

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------//
  const changeState = (v) => {
    return () => setNoteState(v);
  };

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------//
  return noteState === "saved" ? (
    // Saved note
    <div className="flex h-48 w-full flex-col justify-between gap-2 rounded-xl bg-note-light p-4 italic shadow-lg dark:bg-note-dark">
      <textarea
        aria-label="your note text"
        onChange={setNote}
        value={props.text}
        maxLength={200}
        disabled={true}
        className="h-full min-h-6 resize-none bg-transparent text-xl italic focus:outline-none"
      ></textarea>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between h-16">
        <time>{props.date} </time>
        <div className="flex w-28 items-center justify-between h-full">
          <button
            aria-label="edit-note"
            className="rounded-xl bg-button-light px-6 py-1 dark:bg-button-dark h-full"
            onClick={changeState("typing")}
          >
            Edit
          </button>
          <PiTrashDuotone
            className="cursor-pointer w-16"
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "delete_note",
                id: props.id,
              })
            }
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    // Edit note
    <div className="flex h-48 flex-col justify-between rounded-xl gap-2 bg-edit-note-light p-4 shadow-xl dark:bg-edit-note-dark">
      <textarea
        aria-label="your note text"
        placeholder="Type to add a note..."
        onChange={setNote}
        value={noteValue}
        maxLength={200}
        className="h-full min-h-6 resize-none bg-transparent text-xl italic focus:outline-none"
      ></textarea>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between h-16 ">
        <p>{200 - noteValue.length} remaining </p>
        <div className="flex w-28 items-center justify-between h-full ">
          <button
            aria-label="save-note"
            className="rounded-xl bg-note-light px-6 py-1 dark:bg-button-dark h-full"
            onClick={() => {
              dispatch({
                type: "edit_note",
                id: props.id,
                text: noteValue,
              });
              setNoteState("saved");
            }}
          >
            Save
          </button>
          <PiX className="cursor-pointer  w-16" onClick={changeState("saved")}></PiX>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

***Filtered Notes***

```
//FilteredNotes.jsx
import { useContext, useMemo } from "react";
import CurrentNote from "./CurrentNote";
import { NotesContext } from "./notesContext";

export default function FilteredNotes({ query }) {
  // This component filters the notes using the query state. Query state comes from the SearchBar via App.js //

  //----------------------------------------------------------------//
  const notes = useContext(NotesContext);

  //----------------------------------------------------------------//
  const filteredNotes = useMemo(() => {
    return filterItems(notes, query);
  }, [notes, query]);

  function filterItems(notes, query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    return notes.filter((item) => item.text.toLowerCase().includes(query));
  }

  const result = filteredNotes;

  //----------------------------------------------------------------//

  //----------------------------------------------------------------//
  // Creates a CurrentNote component from a list of notes
  let notesList = [];
  if (notes.length > 0) {
    notesList = result.map((note) => {
      return (
        <CurrentNote
          key={note.id}
          id={note.id}
          text={note.text}
          date={note.date}
        />
      );
    });
  } else {
    notesList = [];
  }
  // Used on App.js return.
  return notesList;

  //----------------------------------------------------------------//
}
```

***Notes Context***

```
//NotesContext.jsx
import { createContext } from "react";
//----------------------------------------------------------------//
// Get notes from the browser //
export const initialNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")) || [];

//----------------------------------------------------------------//
// This context is used on the FilteredNotes component
export const NotesContext = createContext(null);
export const NotesDispatchContext = createContext(null);

//----------------------------------------------------------------//
// Reducer to dispatch changes on both child and parent components. App.js notes.
export function notesReducer(notes, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "create_note":
      const newNote = {
        id: notes.length + 1,
        text: action.text,
        date: action.date,
      };
      return [...notes, newNote];

    case "edit_note":
      return notes.map((newNote) => {
        if (newNote.id === action.id) {
          return {
            ...newNote,
            text: action.text,
            date: newNote.date,
          };
        } else {
          return newNote;
        }
      });

    case "delete_note":
      const newNotes = notes.filter((note) => note.id !== action.id);
      return newNotes;

    default:
      throw Error("Unknown action: " + action.type);
  }
}
```

***Header***

```
//Header.jsx
import { PiMoonBold } from "react-icons/pi";

export default function Header(props) {
  // This component handles the display of the header. //
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="text-[2rem] font-bold text-black dark:text-white">
        Notes
      </h1>
      <button
        aria-label="theme-toggle-button"
        className="rounded-lg bg-button-light px-3 py-1 text-text-light shadow-lg dark:bg-button-dark dark:text-text-dark max-sm:hover:shadow-none "
        onClick={props.toggleDarkMode}
      >
        <PiMoonBold />
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

***Search Bar***

```
//SearchBar.jsx
import { PiMagnifyingGlass } from "react-icons/pi";

export default function SearchBar(props) {
  // This component handles the display of the search bar. //
  return (
    <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-center rounded-xl bg-search-bar-light p-3 text-text-light shadow-lg dark:bg-search-bar-dark dark:text-text-dark">
      <PiMagnifyingGlass className="cursor-pointer" />
      <input
        aria-label="search input"
        placeholder="Type to search..."
        value={props.query}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        className="w-full bg-search-bar-light px-4 italic focus:outline-none dark:bg-search-bar-dark"
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```